# Django backend configuration to Stripe, React frontend

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I have created React frontend for Stripe payment,  how can I configure Django Rest Framework server ?

REACT COMPONENT

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";
import axios from "axios";

const StripeBtn = () => {
  const publishableKey = "pk_test_some key";

  const onToken = token => {
    const body = {
      amount: 999,
      token: token
  };
  axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/payment", body)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        alert("Payment Success");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Payment Error: ", error);
        alert("Payment Error");
      });
  };
  return (
    <StripeCheckout
      label="Go Premium" //Component button text
      name="Business LLC" //Modal Header
      description="Upgrade to a premium account today."
      panelLabel="Go Premium" //Submit button in modal
      amount={999} //Amount in cents $9.99
      token={onToken}
      stripeKey={publishableKey}
      image="" //Pop-in header image
      billingAddress={false}
    />
  );
};
export default StripeBtn;
```

Regular Django views, instead of this I need Django Rest framework code to receive the axios POST request.

```
def charge(request): # new
    if request.method == 'POST':
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=500,
            currency='usd',
            description='A Django charge',
            source=request.POST['stripeToken']
        )
        return render(request, 'payments/charge.html')
```

I have installed Stripe in Django and added key's in settings.py and above view is regular Django function to receive Stripe payments.

I was following a tutorial but they were using express.js as backend
https://medium.com/hackernoon/stripe-api-reactjs-and-express-bc446bf08301

Comment: Hi there, your question isn't very clear. If possible could you provide more detail as to the problem you're running into, and any specific error messages that you are encountering?

Comment: that tutorial is for node js backend server. Follow django rest framework tutorial  to build your serializers, views, routes.  https://www.django-rest-framework.org

Comment: Is there any option to use only client side for Stripe ?

Comment: It is always advisable to manipulate any payment gateway or api on server side, as it eliminates accessibility from user side, if you put code on client-side it can be manipulated very easily and very unsecure